# Migrating existing data in cloudant

Tags: cloudant

Say I have a data structure like this in cloudant where this is one record:

```
{
    "UserId": "0014807347",
    "Conq": {
      "reqs": "Testing",
      "tag": "ARRANGEMENT"
    },
    "Outcome": {
      "tag": "ARRANGEMENT",
      "rating": 0
    },
    "id": "cdc11dc55a0006bb544d235e7dc1540a"
  }
```

How could I transform each record of a particular table to add new fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a PUT with the id and current revision with the updated JSON body:

```
curl https://$USERNAME:$PASSWORD@$USERNAME.cloudant.com/$DATABASE/cdc11dc55a0006bb544d235e7dc1540a\
 -X PUT \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -d "$JSON"
{
    "_id": "cdc11dc55a0006bb544d235e7dc1540a",
    "_rev": "1-THE_CURRENT_REV_ID_HERE",
    "UserId": "0014807347",
    "Conq": {
        "reqs": "Testing",
        "tag": "ARRANGEMENT"
    },
    "Outcome": {
      "tag": "ARRANGEMENT",
      "rating": 0
    },
    "my_new_data_field": "My New Content Goes Here"
  }
}
```

You should get a response of the type:

```
{
  "ok":true,
  "id":"cdc11dc55a0006bb544d235e7dc1540a",
  "rev":"2-9176459034" 
}
```

The current revision (indicated by `1-THE_CURRENT_REV_ID_HERE` above) should be the revision you got when the document was last written.